# what is one basic/intermediate regression analysis standard textbook that is math intense

Tags: statistics, reference-request, soft-question, regression

What is one basic/intermediate regression analysis standard textbook that is math intense with proofs/derivations?

Also, i need that one to be comprehensive yet the diffculty is suitable for self study

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regression Analysis by Example By  Samprit Chatterjee and  Ali S. Hadi

http://www.amazon.in/Regression-Analysis-Example-Probability-Statistics/dp/0470905840